# Whats the best practice of using Controller,Service and Repository annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am quite confused with usage of `@Controller`, `@Service` and  `@Repository` in Spring-MVC.

I have couple of questions and would be grateful to have them answered.

- I know controller is used to receive requests from view and make requests to for views to show results to users. My question is that to what extend can I do processing in a class with controller annotation? Should I do all the processing in service annotated class and keep controller for receiving requests and returning responses ONLY? I would like to know whats the best practice?

  Lets say I need to call different methods of service annotated class to process the results should I call them all from controller or pass them to service annotated class? (This is just an example)
- If I would not want to process the results and just willing to send requests to database and receive the results, do I still need to have a service annotated class in between controller and repository?

  Lets say I receive a product id and would like to retrieve and show details of the product.(This is just an example)

Comment: It might be possible right now you don't have any business logic to put in service layer, but you never know what will happen in future. So better to delegate your call through and from service class.

Comment: @NamanGala thanks How about the first bullet point?

Comment: I would suggest to keep your business logic in Service layer and only view specific code in your controller. And for your example, it depends on requirement, if its a full functionality then I would keep it in service layer and if it is just collecting some data from repository then I would make different service method calls from controller only.

Answer (score 8):

I think it is hardly any "best approach" but approach that suit your need.  Here is the approach I used in my past projects, which kind of base on Domain Driven design.

1. Presentation Layer : Controller (@Controller)

   Merely responsible to presenting a business function (provided in Application Service Layer).  Hence mostly delegation to App Service, doing data massaging and presentation-related logic.
2. Application Service Layer : Application Service (@Service)

   High level speaking, it represents business use cases. Hence transaction boundary is set on the methods (as each method is a use-case, hence a unit of work).  As I am against use of anemic model, real business logic should be in the domain model layer.  This layer mostly make use of domain layer to compose of a meaningful use case.  Mostly data transformations (depending on your design), and delegations to domain layer artifacts.
3. Domain Layer : Model, Domain Service (@Service), Repository (@Repository) etc

   Business logic are in domain models, or Domain Services.  Repository are the artifacts to retrieve domain models.
4. Infrastructure Layer

   Infrastructure-dependent implementation of some domain artifacts.

Go back to your question:

- There is no right or wrong.  If you are making a totally self-contained simple application, there may be no benefit of splitting the role of Controller and Application Service layer.  Also, for people that are so get used to anemic model development, you may need a Service just to put your business logic in.  So, you need to ask yourself, what is your purpose to have certain layer in your design, and is it something that is really meaningful to you.  For my approach, I think it is already quite clear on what to do for which layer. You may take it as reference if you want.
- Similar answer: If you are doing the role of Presentation + Application Service in your Controller, there is no special reason of making up another Service.  But if you want to maintain a presentation-neutral application service layer, then you should provide those "CRUD" actions through your app service.

Comment: thanks, what do you mean by presentation-neutral? I receive product id and use that to show the details of the selected product.

Comment: What I mean is actually presentation-layer-technology-neutral. Now we may choose to use Spring MVC but later we may use other thing like CXF or your custom protocol whatsoever. By abstracting out the presentation layer, and leave app service as plain pojo, it will be easy for you to replace the presentation layer or reuse same use-cases through other channels.  Again, it may not apply to you, it largely depends on your design decision.

Answer (score 3):

Well depends on requirements, I think you would be better off to keep controllers clean, they are used for presentation so you should only keep whatever is related to presentation layer there, nevertheless, if you need to pass the inputs to a service class and from there call other service methods, I would say do not bother creating a new method in service class just call the service methods directly.

Lets say these methods are in service class, I think it wont make sense to send the input to a service class, and have following code in there. I would suggest to keep this code in controller and call the methods as following:

```
if(input is valid){
      result1 = serviceClass.dothisstuff(input);
      result2 = serviceClass.thenthisstuff(result1);
}else{
      result1 = serviceClass.dothosestuff(input);
      result2 = serviceClass.thenthosestuff(result1);
}
```

I would say use all three layers all the time for the sake of future requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Converting comments into answer.

- I would suggest to keep your *business logic* in Service layer and only view specific code in your controller. And for your example, it is primarily opinion base and it depends on requirement, if its a full functionality then I would keep it in service layer and if it is just collecting some data from repository then I would make different service method calls from controller only.
- It might be possible right now you don't have any business logic to put in service layer, but you never know what will happen **in future**. So better to delegate your call through and from service class.